# Django CSRF failure on ajax post requests on Opera only

Tags: django, opera, django-csrf

Ok so AJAX POST requests work fine in Mozilla and Chromium, but fail in Opera. I get the standard CSRF error (403).  I tried different versions of Opera and they failed in every one I tried. Btw, I'm using the jquery/django snippet that sets X-CSRFToken in the header, as verified in the "bad Opera request" below.

I made a view in a different project that was very simple and ajax post requests worked fine in Opera. I looked at the request details and see differences. The good request doesn't set any weird X-Opera-Info and other opera params even thought I'm using the same browser. If this is the issue, is there a way to remove those extra params? Or does anyone have any other advice or ideas on what the issue may be? I know it's not my view function because I tried just returning an HttpResponse immediately and even that gets 403'd. Thanks a million guys.

```
####################
OPERA GOOD REQUEST
##############
Request details
POST /test HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.00
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test
Cookie: csrftoken=1c6441404c991f7ae3b6d7d49f91f280
Cookie2: $Version=1
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
TE: deflate, gzip, chunked, identity, trailers
Content-Length: 6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
X-CSRFToken: 1c6441404c991f7ae3b6d7d49f91f280
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

###################
OPERA BAD REQUEST
####################
Request details
POST http://facebook.example.com/remove-person HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; U; en) Presto/2.7.62 Version/11.00
Host: facebook.example.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0
Referer: http://facebook.example.com/
Cookie: signed_request=5-f0_7pZLILrp6MLocsdMoNYAaZr-wCnU2cPbLC1bZg.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImV4cGlyZXMiOjEzMDg4MTYwMDAsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTMwODgxMTQyNywib2F1dGhfdG9rZW4iOiIyMjMyNDY5NDEwMjc3MTR8Mi5BUURVRGM2ZFFLSElnN1h3LjM2MDAuMTMwODgxNjAwMC4xLTU0MDIwMjZ8b2QtX1diNTh3aG1wTnNHYUh4cTNtOVBpWkswIiwidXNlciI6eyJjb3VudHJ5IjoidXMiLCJsb2NhbGUiOiJlbl9VUyIsImFnZSI6eyJtaW4iOjIxfX0sInVzZXJfaWQiOiI1NDAyMDI2In0; csrftoken=d4cdc6a75ed264d295a410dd98982c42; fbs_223246941027714="access_token=223246941027714%7C2.AQBlhzavZjzd8c7J.3600.1308819600.1-5402026%7CdsD6VESpGJb3m0EdD1mhFZtDI24&base_domain=example.com&expires=1308819600&secret=QaTNS988wl0FU6A0LG9qDQ__&session_key=2.AQBlhzavZjzd8c7J.3600.1308819600.1-5402026&sig=61e7e13091501f35793d3cda8c20835b&uid=5402026"
Cookie2: $Version=1
Connection: Keep-Alive, TE
TE: deflate, gzip, chunked, identity, trailers
Content-Length: 14
X-Opera-Info: ID=448, p=4, f=15, sw=1440, sh=900
X-Opera-ID: e79c37b56a58510d26b56882453bddb6d2c2dae858129139113f6346ea23ca6b
X-Opera-Host: r18-02:12420
X-OA: 1322 b5834cb13259fbd50b87b576b5e8b9a8bcc1384478c2ea79cc65614dc1b67c27
X-OB: evenes
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: */*
X-CSRFToken: d4cdc6a75ed264d295a410dd98982c42
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar problem. I was trying to do, for the first time, a post from AJAX on a view where Django wasn't sending a CSRF cookie. For reasons I can't explain, this was working on all browsers I tried except Opera.

This scenario is [described in the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#page-uses-ajax-without-any-html-form), and they suggest using the `ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator.

Another thing you can do if it is too burdensome to wrap all the potential views with that decorator is to add something like this to your base template:

```
<script>
var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token }}";
</script>
```

And then whenever you do an AJAX post, always include the key pair `csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token` with your POST data.

Once I did the above, my posts with Opera started working.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you disable Opera Turbo? These extra headers seem to be Turbo-related and perhaps this makes some kind of difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
X-CSRFToken: {{ csrf_token }}}
```

value should be send from client in AJAX request HTTP headers to be recognized by Django